# SSIS package to export query result to CSV does not export all the records

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, export-to-csv

I am developing on Visual studio 2015 (with data tools extensions) a simple SSIS package: it has a connection (Sql server 2008), an OLEDB Origin, containing a query, connected to a flat file destination.

- The db connection is tested an it works;
- The oleDb origin works, there are no variables in the query;
- The query inside the OleDb origin returns about 700 records
- The preview in the OleDb returns 200 records (as configured)
- The mapping between query and file is 1:1, all the fields from query are included in the resulting csv in the same order.

When I run the package the csv file is created, it contains exactly the needed fields but only 169 records (expected about 700).

I compared the contents of the csv with the data from the query and noticed that:

- Records are not in the same order
- The records not exported are seemingly random placed in the sql results (I supposed that the exported were the first ones but it is not the case)
- The data in the missing records has nothing strange (no long string or null values, or out of range values)
- Repeating the execution several times the extracted and missing records are exactly the same, in the same order.

Do you have any suggestion to solve this? I need to export all records in the same order. It seems that the Order by clause in the query is ignored by the export and that records exported are a sample of the original ones.

Comment: Thats seems very strange, unless you are using a copy of a .csv file, which had previous formats on the spreadsheet. Create a new .csv(not copy). Take the result set of your query and manually insert in the .csv. Delete the rows. Then in your SSIS package map the data. See if that works

Comment: *Records are not in the same order*. What do you mean by this? Data is not stored in any specific order in SQL Server so what "order" are you talking about? The only way to ensure the order of data in a query is using `ORDER BY`, and the only way in SSIS is using a Sort transformation. SSIS won't just not export certain rows, there will be reason. What the reason that is could be many; for example a conversion error, a filtered result set, filter dataflow, etc

Comment: Make sure that rows aren't being discarded at any point by a silent error handling that's omitting failed records. The `ORDER BY` clause at source will ensure that rows are processed in order. Review the output window of the DTS after execution to check anomalies.

Comment: Please double check your OLEDB source query, you might be missing a simple logic in your output query

Comment: You might want to make sure you are looking at the right csv. How many records are going into the output object?

Comment: What is your query, and what is an example of a missing row that you expect to be there?

Comment: I can partially reply to comments because I cannot access to DB now. @mvisser: I started with a clean export folder, the csv file is created from scratch by the dtsx.

Comment: @Larnu: the query contains an order by clause, executing it in managenent studio I see the expected order. The query in the dtsx is copy/pasted from management studio but the csv order is different.

Comment: @KeithL: I expect about 700 records, as extracted when I execute the query in management studio, the scv instead contains about 170. I analysed the missing records, they do not have anything strange (nulls, long strings...)

Comment: @TabAlleman: I cannot share the query because of customer's policy. It is quite simple, a SELECT [lots of fields] FROM table T1 [some left and inner joins] WHERE [very simple criteria] ORDER BY [3 fields]. No calls to UDF, windowing functions, parameters, variabiles and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the issue, my fault.

I checked and saved the data from sql management studio, then developed the dtsx.

Meanwhile that data (that I believed to be unmodifiable) has been modified, therefore the dtsx showed the updated version and I checked it against the old version.